# Blackberry10 Developer Certificate not generated

Tags: android, certificate, blackberry-10, code-signing

I am developing a game for Blackberry 10 using "Runtime for Android apps".I have completed the development, but when i am going to create development certificate to create.bar file, it is throwing exception as " **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen.getSelfCertificate**".

[image]

My barsigner.csk and barsigner.db are already created.What could be the possible solution for this.I am using only simulator for testing.Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have able to solve my problem using command line tool. I have downloaded "CommandLineTools_1.5.2" and copied "blackberry.tools.SDK" into "C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde". after that write a simple command in cmd "blackberry-keytool -genkeypair -storepass  -dname "cn=" *.It will generate author.p12 file and after that you can generate debug token. :)